# Image Processing: Edge detection of the tumor on tomogram. Сalculation area of the tumor

Tags: image-processing

The task is to identify the image region of the tumor.

[image: tomography of kidneys with tumor (white area on the left kidney)]

I try to use example from documentation centre:

```
tom1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ4fR.jpg"];
tumor = SelectComponents[
          DeleteBorderComponents[ Binarize[ tom1, {0.75, 1}]], 
          {"Area", "Holes"}, 2800 < #1 < 2900 && #2 > 0 &];
circle = ComponentMeasurements[ 
           ImageMultiply[ tom1, tumor], 
           {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2]];
Show[ tom1, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle @@ # & /@ circle}]]
```

but get unsatisfactory result:

[image: tumor detection]

i try to identify tumor like this but selection was noisy:

```
SelectComponents[
  DeleteBorderComponents[ Binarize[ tom1, {0.75, 1}]], 
  {"Area", "Holes"}, 2800 < #1 < 2900 && #2 > 0 &]
```

[image: tumor]

So, can you help me to make clearer allocation of the tumor and then calculate the area of ​​selection?

Comment: If this is a tomogram wouldn't it be better to measure the tumor volume in 3D instead of the area of a single slice?

Answer (score 14):

Your approach is quite good. I would smooth the data a bit and do an `Opening` to cut one extra part:

```
tom1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ4fR.jpg"];
smooth = GaussianFilter[tom1, 2];
tumor = SelectComponents[
  DeleteBorderComponents[
   Opening[Binarize[smooth, {0.8, 1}], 1]], {"Area", "Holes"}, 
  2000 < #1 < 2200 &];

HighlightImage[tom1, tumor]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And for the second part of your question, you can then use, as pointed out by bobthechemist

```
ComponentMeasurements[tumor, "Area"]
(* {1 -> 2062.} *)
```

Comment: +1. Should you include something like `ComponentMeasurements[tumor, "Area"]` to answer the 2nd part of the question?

Comment: @bobthechemist I have missed this completely. Thanks.